Зависимость .readline от типа цикла
Почему в зависимости от типа цикла метод .readline выдает разные результаты?
В первом случае запускаю цикл:
testfile = open('Тест.txt','r')
for i in testfile:
    i = testfile.readline()
    print(i, end="")
testfile.close()

Получаю результат:
2w
4w
6w
8w
Во втором цикле:
testfile = open('Тест.txt','r')
i = testfile.readline()
while i:
    i = testfile.readline()
    print(i, end="")
testfile.close()

получаю результат:
2w
3q
4w
5q
6w
7q
8w
9q
При этом проигнорирована первая строка - 1q
Файл Тест.txt:
1q
2w
3q
4w
5q
6w
7q
8w
9q

Пожалуйста добавьте пример исходного файла Тест.txt

Добавил пример исходного файла Тест.txt в тексте вопроса. Не знаю, можно ли его добавить в виде атачмента.

При использовании цикла for:
testfile = open('Тест.txt', 'r')
for stroka in testfile:
    stroka = testfile.readline()
    print(stroka, end="")
testfile.close()

Что происходит:
В этом цикле вы итерируете по объекту файла testfile. Каждый раз, когда происходит итерация, Python автоматически вызывает testfile.readline(), чтобы получить следующую строку.
Однако внутри цикла вы снова вызываете testfile.readline(), что приводит к тому, что вы пропускаете каждую вторую строку файла. Таким образом, вы получаете только строки с четными номерами (2w, 4w, 6w, 8w)
При использовании цикла while:
testfile = open('Тест.txt', 'r')
stroka = testfile.readline()
while stroka:
    stroka = testfile.readline()
    print(stroka, end="")
testfile.close()

Что происходит:
В этом цикле вы сначала считываете первую строку файла с помощью stroka = testfile.readline().
Затем, в условии цикла while, вы снова считываете строку перед тем, как ее напечатать. В результате вы печатаете строки, начиная со второй (3q, 4w, 5q и так далее).
Таким образом, вы пропускаете первую строку и печатаете все последующие.
Решение проблемы:
С циклом for:
 testfile = open('Тест.txt', 'r')
    for stroka in testfile:
        print(stroka, end="")
    testfile.close()

С циклом while:
testfile = open('Тест.txt', 'r')
stroka = testfile.readline()
while stroka:
    print(stroka, end="")
    stroka = testfile.readline()
testfile.close()


А если в цикле for мне надо не напечатать строку, а получить ее значение. Например, присвоить переменной. Как быть в этом случае?

И почему в цикле for print() вызывает чтение строки, а в цикле while нет?

@winkot если вам нужно присвоить значение строки вашей переменной, то просто напишите a = stroka

@winkot print() не вызывает чтение строки, он просто выводит данные, которые мы получили после чтения строки

Почему в цикле for Python автоматически вызывает testfile.readline(), в в цикле while - нет?

@winkot потому что for i in testfile создает итератор который дергает testfile читая строку. for i in testfile сам по себе означает "прочитай построчно".

А как же for i in testfile понимает, что это именно текстовый файл? Ведь цикл for ... in может применяться не только с текстовыми файлами.

А если это не будет не текстовый файл, то и действия должны применяться другие. Как for i in testfile это поймет?

@winkot дык вы сами ему указываете во флагах. Есть 'b' - значит бинарный файл и метод open вернет бинарный ридер, иначе текстовый.
